# How to convert a photo without losing quality?

Tags: images, conversion, png, bmp

I have to convert a bmp into another standard format, without losing quality. To which format shall I convert it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already got it in the tags. [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) is another lossless format that is widely supported. Depending on the software you use to create it, PNG images are compressed by filtering and using the [DEFLATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) algorithm, which means that their file size will probably be smaller than the original BMP.

You can also try to convert it to a TIFF image, but that format offers more features that you might not even need.

Comment: PNG is lossless and it is compressed, resulting in much smaller file sizes than BMP